# Handling submit in React/Redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I want to capture the form values when a user submits a form. The React tutorial shows this:

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  handleAuthorChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({author: e.target.value});
  },
  handleTextChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var author = this.state.author.trim();
    var text = this.state.text.trim();
    if (!text || !author) {
      return;
    }
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
```

This style pushes all changes into state via a handling function per input. If I were to go full on with Redux, I believe I would add actions and action creators to the mix, which seems like a lot of overhead.

Note the argument to `handleSubmit` is an event.

I came across a following React/Redux starter kit which looks to be much easier to work with. It uses a smart/container component and dumb/presentational component combination:

[Container](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/containers/Survey/Survey.js)

```
@connect(
  () => ({}),
  {initialize})
export default class Survey extends Component {
  ...

  handleSubmit = (data) => {
    window.alert('Data submitted! ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    this.props.initialize('survey', {});
  }

  render()
    return ( <SurveyForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/> )
  ...
```

[Presentational](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/components/SurveyForm/SurveyForm.js)

```
class SurveyForm extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    ...
  }
}
```

What I'm unclear on is why the handler for the form's `onSubmit` handler is taking in an event for its argument for the Facebook tutorial, but why the starter kit's `onSubmit` handler is taking the form data... The starter kit is leveraging the `redux-form` package but I don't see it directly affecting how this handler should be behaving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is in `redux-form` being used as an [ES2016 decorator](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.m12yng174) on the `SurveyForm` class.

```
...
@reduxForm({
  form: 'survey',
  fields: ['name', 'email', 'occupation', 'currentlyEmployed', 'sex'],
  validate: surveyValidation,
  asyncValidate,
  asyncBlurFields: ['email']
})
export default
class SurveyForm extends Component {
...
```

The decorator will act as a wrapping function for the `SurveyForm`, returning a wrapping component.

As you may even have noticed, the `SurveyForm` component accepts an `handleSubmit` prop which is not being passed down in the container. This is because it is provided by the `@reduxForm` decorator. The event is then handled and only the formData is returned to the container handler, the top-level `onSubmit` prop.

Essentially, you can think about it as `reduxForm` returning a wrapped `SurveyForm` component.

You can dive into the code [there](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/createReduxForm.js), but be warned, it's pretty dense.

Comment: I believe you are correct, though `handleSubmit` does appear to be passed down as a prop: `render() return ( <SurveyForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/> )` Did you mean something else?

Comment: In the code, SurveyForm never calls `this.props.onSubmit` but calls `this.props.handleSubmit`. Your handler is being bind on the `onSubmit` prop, meaning it never gets called by `SurveyForm` directly. In the reduxForm code, you can see it calling `this.props.onSubmit`. This is tricky because the names are quite similar, but in essence SurveyForm calls `this.props.handleSubmit` (provided by reduxForm), which in returns calls `this.props.onSubmit` (your handler).